# Errors starting Docker on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu

Since some time ago, when I start Docker on Ubuntu (on WSL2, WIndows 11) I am getting errors:

```
❯ sudo service docker start
[sudo] password for anat:
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/devices: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/pids: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/misc: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on cgroup, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                 [ OK ]
```

This happens on both distros, Ubuntu 20.04, and Ubuntu 22.04. For Ubuntu-20.04, I did clean installation today (Ubuntu and Docker) but it did not help. I think, these errors appeared after one of the Windows updates. Before, I never had such errors.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution for this issue.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and add:

```
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
```